# why is that an array is having a "_ractive" property?

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I've noticed that every array that is asigned to ractive via data has a _ractive property... the thing is, this array seems to have a _ractive: Object which is a key:value pair, and this is not suposed to be in arrays.
[image]

so i added a screenshot about chrome inspection to make the point clear.

can somebody help me to understand this better ?

Comment: Why isn't that supposed to be in arrays? It sounds like this is where `ractive` keeps metadata about the array.

Comment: Arrays are objects, they can have properties in addition to the numbered ones.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zLTsR/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ractive array modification is explained in detail in the docs [here](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/array-modification). As part of tracking array modification, the array methods are wrapped and:

> Ractive adds a (non-enumerable, in modern browsers) _ractive property
>   to arrays, which contains information about which Ractive instances
>   depend on the array, and which keypaths it is assigned to.

You can stop array modification by using `modifyArrays: false`, but you then need to call `ractive.update` yourself, **or** you can use the ractive array modification methods like `ractive.push(array, item)` (an additional advantage being that this call returns a promise called when transitions if any complete, if that is relevant to your use).